# Clarification on optimizing Single-constructor datatypes in GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc

I was reading about how to optimize my Haskell code and came across a note about [Single-constructor datatypes in GHC](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Data_types).

Excerpt:

> GHC loves single-constructor datatypes, such as tuples. A single-constructor datatype can be unpacked when it is passed to a strict function. For example, given this function:
>
> ```
> f (x,y) = ...
> ```
>
> GHC's strictness analyser will detect that f is strict in its argument, and compile the function like this:
>
> ```
> f z = case z of (x,y) -> f' x y
> f' x y = ...
> ```
>
> where f is called the wrapper, and f' is called the worker. The wrapper is inlined everywhere, so for example if you had a call to f like this:
>
> ```
> ... f (3,4) ...
> ```
>
> this will end up being compiled to
>
> ```
> ... f' 3 4 ...
> ```
>
> and the tuple has been completely optimised away.

Does this mean I should go through my program and wrap up all function arguments into one tuple? I don't really see how this is an optimization when the tuple gets unwrapped anyway.

Is this an alternative to the `INLINE` pragma? Should I use both? Only one? Is one better?

Comment: This does interact with inlining and strictness analysis (and e.g. funbox-strict of course).  This is all really easy to see in core if you want to experiment.

Comment: Yo, no, definitely don't wrap everything in tuples! That's a lot of work for you, and the *best case* described by this text is that GHC sees through your stupidity and undoes it, rewriting your newly refactored code back to what it was before you did the refactor. Worst case you do a lot of work and GHC doesn't notice it can undo it, leaving you with a slower, more memory-hungry program!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I don't really see how this is an optimization when the tuple gets unwrapped anyway.

*That is* the optimisation: that the tuple gets unwrapped. IOW, the program that eventually runs never contains a tuple at all, it just contains a two-argument function call.

One might also put this in more pessimistic terms: ab initio, *tuples are inherently bad* for performance. That's because a tuple argument requires *three* pointer indirections: a thunk for the entire tuple, a thunk for the `fst` element, and a thunk for the `snd` element. So in principle, for performance it's a very bad idea to wrap your data into tuples. (Better put it in `data` structs with strict fields.) That is, of course, unless you really do need laziness at all of these spots.

*However*, and that's what the quote is all about, in practice it's generally still fine to use tuples in GHC, because it can usually optimise the indirection away if it can prove that it isn't actually needed.